# how to get the current zoom in openlayers

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

i have a question. i need to know the actual zoom of the open layers map

```
$scope.refreshMap = function (lat, long) {
    map.setView(new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [long, lat], 
        zoom: "here I do not know what to put"
    }));
};
```

i try with `map.getZoom()` but it doesn't work.
the logcat throws me a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'getZoom'
```

i'm using the openlayers Version: v3.16.0

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Zoom is a property of [`ol.View`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html). So `ol.Map` has a `ol.View` that has zoom level, center, projection to say some.

```
map.getView().getZoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.refreshMap = function (lat, long) {
            var actualZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
            console.log(z);

            map.setView(new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [long, lat], //long,lat
                zoom: actualZoom
            }));
};
```